# a small question about abelian variety

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Given an abelian variety over $k$, say $A$, and suppose $O_L\hookrightarrow End(A)$, let $P$ be a fractional ideal of $L$, I'm a little confused why $A\otimes_{O_L} P$ is an abelian variety. In my understanding, if we consider $A$ corresponding to the representatble functor from the category of varieties (schemes) over $k$ to the category of Abelian groups, $$F_A: V \mapsto Hom(V,A),$$ 
then $A\otimes_{O_L} P$ corresponds to the functor 
$$V\mapsto F_A(V)\otimes P.$$
So is it very easy to see this functor is representable (in the category of varieties) given $F_A$ is representable?
Thanks.

Comment: Here's an idea. The abelian variety you seek is isogenous to $A$. Can you come up with a finite subgroup of $A$ that you can quotient out by in order to get the abelian variety you're after?

Comment: Ah, Thanks! Assume $P^{-1}$ is an integral ideal in $O_L$, then this subgroup should be $\cap_{\alpha in P^{-1}} Ker \alpha$.